# Targetting text but not targeting sibling element with CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

In the example below, I'm trying to target the "$59.00"

```
<div class="ProductPriceRating">
    <em>
        <strike class="RetailPriceValue">$69.00</strike> 
        $59.00
    </em>
</div>
```

I'm a little stuck on this.

Comment: CSS is unable to target text nodes

Comment: How about Jquery? Can I target it with Jquery and then wrap an element around it?

Comment: Yes, this is very much possible that find the text you are looking for, and wrap it up with some element. But in this case, you better wrap it up initially while creating HTML nodes.

Comment: I can't manually change the HTML in this case. I'm working on a hosted platform that doesn't let me

Comment: ok, so added the jQuery option as you asked for in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this unless you are willing to change your DOM or you are willing to override.

So either you need to wrap the text using a `span` element and than target like

```
div.ProductPriceRating > em > span {

}
```

Else if you cannot change the DOM than you need to use two selectors, where first will apply the style to `em` and the next one will override that using `strike`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/K5Hg2/)

```
div.ProductPriceRating > em {
    color: red;
}

div.ProductPriceRating > em > strike {
    color: black;
}
```

---

The other way you can use is `:not` but if you are using `color` than inheritance will cause you problems

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/K5Hg2/1/)

```
div.ProductPriceRating em:not(.RetailPriceValue) {
    background: red;
}
```

---

As you commented, you are willing to go with jQuery, than here you go, we are wrapping the node using jQuery..

```
$(".ProductPriceRating em").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType != 1; //or return this.nodeType == 3;  <-- Preferable 
}).wrap("<span></span>");
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LTk8U/)

Comment: I cannot change the dom on this directly. Only way would be through javascript/jquery

Comment: `Only way would be through javascript/jquery`. No, the second demo above shows how to do it with simple CSS alone.

Comment: @ralph.m No, inheritance is an issue there, so I've kept my statement as is, I didn't provided `:not` solution before because of this reason, OP wants color and not the background, but again I edited and re shared :)

Comment: I tried jquery $('.ProductPriceRating em:not(.RetailPriceValue)').wrap("<div class='new'></div>");, but didn't work

Comment: @JackPilowsky Ok, if you are willing to go with jQuery than I will provide one

Comment: This one worked. The other solutions might be right too though

Comment: @JackPilowsky Others solutions work, it's just a matter of compactness of code, Hasheems answer is pretty close to me, he used `.find` with the condition which I've commented out in my answer

Answer (score 1):

> How about jQuery? Can I target it with Jquery and then wrap an element
>   around it?

Well, you could select the text node and add a wrapper as follows:

```javascript
$('.ProductPriceRating')
  .find("em")
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3; // filter the text node
  }).wrap("<span></span>");
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/6g2GJ/)**

**CSS:**

```css
.ProductPriceRating span {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: @Mr.Alien OOPS :) I was writing the answer :P

Comment: Anyways +1 for coming pretty close to me :D

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to select specific text in CSS, but in your case you can do it overwriting the CSS property.

Here is an example:

```
.ProductPriceRating em{font-weight:700; font-size:20px; color:darkgreen}
.ProductPriceRating em .RetailPriceValue{color:#AAA; font-size:11px}
```

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/T6f7y/)

**Addition:**

As you mentioned in the comment above, that you want to do it with jQuery like wrapping up the text with an element. here is the example for that:

```
$(".ProductPriceRating").each(function(c, obj){
    obj = $(obj).find(">em"),
    retailPrice = obj.find(".RetailPriceValue").detach(),
    newNode = $("<b/>").text($.trim($(obj).text()));

    obj.html(newNode).prepend(retailPrice);
});
```

[<kbd>jQuery Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/T6f7y/1/)

See the CSS there, both are separate working...